# Send email with unix sendmail

Tags: c++, email, unix, sendmail

The goal is to send email on Unix machine like php `mail` function does. On StackOverflow I already found a function for doing it, but maybe somebody can suggest a more elegant solution or a solution without `fprintf` and `fwrite`? Because I do not use `printf` in my *C++* program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
int sendmail(const char *to, const char *from, const char *subject, const char *message)
{
    int retval = -1;
    FILE *mailpipe = popen("usr/lib/sendmail -t", "w");
    if (mailpipe != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(mailpipe, "To: %s\n", to);
        fprintf(mailpipe, "From: %s\n" from);
        fprintf(mailpipe, "Subject: %s\n\n", subject);
        fwrite(message, 1, strlen(message), mailpipe);
        fwrite(".\n", 1, 2, mailpipe);
        pclose(mailpipe);
        retval = 0;
     }
     else
     {
         perror("Failed to invoke sendmail”);
     }
     return retval;
}
```

Comment: There is no standard way to do this AFAIK.

Comment: elagant or easiest way? seems php written on c++. how php realize this function?

Comment: PHP is written in C.  You can freely use C with C++ for the most part.

Comment: you can't avoid input. As a alternative, you can use ofstream instead of fprintf.

Comment: @Sachin maybe example of how to use ofstream correctly indtead of fprintf? thanks. (the topic is still actual)

Comment: refer www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/

Comment: [Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SMTPClientSession.html) may be helpful and [tutorial](http://axistasoft.com/blog/poco/item/sending-e-mail-messages-using-poco-smtpclientsession-class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you have only two ways of doing that. First is to use a sendmail subprocess. At a lower level, you will communicate with it through pipes and AFAIK there is no standard way to associate a C++ stream to a pipe. So you will have to use the good old `write`, `fwrite` or `fprints` to output your data.

The other way would be to directly open a socket to a smtp server and use the SMTP protocol (EHLO or HELO, MAIL FROM:, RCPT TO: DATA and BYE), dealing with the responses of the server ... :-( and anyway, there is no more standard way to create a C++ stream from a socket !

If the reason why you do not want to use fwrite and fprintf is that you do not want to use the C standard library, directly use the system calls : prepare the strings to be sent with a C++ string or a `strstream`, and send the result to the pipe directly with write. And if you do not want to use write either, just ask yourself how does the C++ library write to files ...